# Time off tracking tool - Creating a cell value that increments by a designated amount on specific days of the year

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I am using MS Excel 2007 and I am creating a worksheet that will help employees track Paid Time Off (PTO).  The number of hours an employee has available to use increments by a specific amount of hours twice a month on specific days.  Specifically the 2nd and the 17th of each month.
I have put the number of hours to add each pay period in one cell lets say A1, I put the =today() function in another cell lets say B1, and the total number of hours available in yet another cell lets say C1.
I would like the value in the total hours avail cell(C1) to increment by the number that I specified in cell A1 each 2nd and each 17th of each month when the =today() cell reaches that particular month and day.  For example:

An employee gets 5 hours of PTO each pay period.  Pay periods end on the 2nd and the 17th of each month.
Lets say that todays date is March 2nd 2011. The calculation would need to total all the hours accrued on each pay period from the begining of the year, Jan 1, 2011 to the present day.
The total for march 2nd would equal 25.  On Mach 17th, the number would increment by 5 (the value in A1) and the total would be 30.  This would continue to the end of the year.

I hope this make sense - I'm not really a programmer type of person.

Comment: Thank you both for you answers.  Both work very well and as a result, not only do I have a working worksheet, I have a better understanding of formulas and how they work with regards to date functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all with one formula:

```
=hrs*(2*(MONTH(today)-1)+IF(DAY(today)>=day_one,1,0)+IF(DAY(today)>=day_two,1,0))
```

In your example:

```
hrs = 5
day_one = 2
day_two = 17
today = today's date
```

Using the cell references you gave, it would look like this:

```
=$A$1*(2*(MONTH($B$1)-1)+IF(DAY($B$1)>=2,1,0)+IF(DAY($B$1)>=17,1,0))
```

You can, of course, use the TODAY() function directly in the formula if you prefer:

```
=$A$1*(2*(MONTH(TODAY())-1)+IF(DAY(TODAY())>=2,1,0)+IF(DAY(TODAY())>=17,1,0))
```

Here is how it breaks down:

1. `MONTH(today)` returns a number between 1 and 12 representing the current month
2. `2*(MONTH(today)-1)` returns the number of whole pay periods that have been passed in all of the months *before* this month (since there will be exactly two in each month)
3. `DAY(today)` returns the current day of the month
4. `+IF(DAY(today)>=number,1,0)` will add one to the total, as long as the current day of the month is greater than or equal to `number`.
5. `2*(MONTH(today)-1)+IF(DAY(today)>=day_one,1,0)+IF(DAY(today)>=day_two,1,0)` gives you the total number of pay periods that have been passed as of today's date
6. Wrapping the whole thing in `=hrs*(...)` will then give the total number of hours available as of today

Comment: Thanks - I managed to get this to work (still trying to figure out what the formula is doing but it is a workable solution as I believe the other answer is to once I can see the value for the third row.

Comment: The formula is really just counting the number of pay periods between today and January 1 of this year, and then multiplying that number by a constant number of hours per pay period (5).

Comment: The number of pay periods is `2*(month - 1)` plus 0, 1 or 2, depending on the current day of the month.

Comment: Ah ha - I got it now.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a super user question than a programming one but...

This is what the below example shows.  The person carried over 40 hrs as of Jan 1st 2011.
The person has used 16 hours year to date.
E2 is where all the heavy lifting is done.  It determines if the moment in time excel is opened has a day of > 17th (probably should be >=) then take the rate *2 since 2 instances have occured where they get time.  If the date is >2 (probably should be >=2) then take the rate alone * number of months (ignore the current one) then adds in the carryover and pulls out the time used.

copy formula:

```
=IF(DAY(NOW())>=17,I3*2,IF(DAY(NOW())>=2,I3))+((MONTH(NOW())-1)*I3*2)+D2-F2
```

[image]

Comment: Haha well, +1 `:)` Great minds, and all that... I do like the way you included a subtraction for the number of hours already used.

Comment: This is helpful and the formula works however, it is not picking up the other pay periods values only the value I put in the carryover cell.  Are ther more rows in your example.  I can only see rows 1 and 2 and columns A thru L.  I noticed that the formula is looking for a value or a formula in cell I3 but I cannot determine what formula or value is in I3.  Also, how does it determine how many pay periods have happened since January 1st?

Comment: Ah....I think I figured it out.  The value in cell I3 is 5, the actual rate.  Cell I2 is just a header if I'm guessing correct.  When I put the accrual rate number in cell I3, the formula works.

Comment: you got it!  Note: the use of to test change the system clock date time and close /reopen the excel sheet and you'll see that the "current" changes  (so jump to dec 16 reopen nothing changes jump to dec 17th and voila the 84 is now 89. (and yes both solutions appear to work)